# How to make my code thread-safe when my shared variable can change anytime?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-local

Here is a question that has been asked many times, I have double-checked numerous issues that have been raised formerly but none gave me an answer element so I thought I would put it here.

The question is about making my code thread-safe in java knowing that there is only one shared variable but it can change anytime and actually I have the feeling that the code I am optimizing has not been thought for a multi-threading environment, so I might have to think it over...

Basically, I have one class which can be shared between, say, 5 threads. This class has a private property 'myProperty' which can take 5 different values (one for each thread). The problem is that, once it's instantiated by the constructor, that value should not be changed anymore for the rest of the thread's life.

I am pretty well aware of some techniques used to turn most of pieces of code "thead-safe" including locks, the "synchronized" keyword, volatile variables and atomic types but I have the feeling that these won't help in the current situation as they do not prevent the variable from being modified.

Here is the code :

```
// The thread that calls for the class containing the shared variable //

public class myThread implements Runnable {

     @Autowired
     private Shared myProperty;

     //some code
}

// The class containing the shared variable //

public class Shared {

      private String operator;
      private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

      public void inititiate(){
           this.lock.lock()
           try{
                 this.operator.initiate() // Gets a different value depending on the calling thread
           } finally {
                 this.lock.unlock();
           }
      } 

      // some code        
}
```

As it happens, the above code only guarantees that two threads won't change the variable at the same time, but the latter will still change. A "naive" workaround would consist in creating a table (operatorList) for instance (or a list, a map, etc. ) associating an operator with its calling thread's ID, this way each thread would just have to access its operator using its id in the table but doing this would make us change all the thread classes which access the shared variable and there are many. Any idea as to how I could store the different operator string values in an exclusive manner for each calling thread with minimal changes (without using magic) ?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish? You want to uniquely identify threads?

Comment: So do you have (or want) one instance of `Shared` (in which case, the `myProperty` cannot take 5 values), or 5 instances of `Shared` (in which case, is that how you've set Spring to Autowire?)

Comment: @Elias : I want each thread to see a different value for Shared#operator

Comment: @racraman : I want one instance of Shared for all 5 threads and for each thread to see a different value in myProperty - About Spring, I have not built the software I am only optimizing it but I am interested in knowing how to set Spring to autowire ! (If I had to guess I'd say that it has been set to autowire one instance of Shared for all the threads)

Comment: Ah, the term you are looking for is "thread local".

Comment: You guess right - Spring defaults to Singleton scope (some interesting reading here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31629993/is-spring-default-scope-singleton-or-not/31630098#31630098 ). For this question, yes - ThreadLocal is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I totally understand the situation, but if you want to ensure that each thread uses a thread-specific instance for a variable, the solution is use a variable of type `ThreadLocal<T>`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure I understood your question correctly, but I'll give it a shot anyway. Correct me if I'm wrong.

> A "naive" workaround would consist in creating a table (operatorList)
>   for instance (or a list, a map, etc. ) associating an operator with
>   its calling thread's ID, this way each thread would just have to
>   access its operator using its id in the table but doing this would
>   make us change all the thread classes which access the shared variable
>   and there are many.

There's already something similar in Java - the [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) class?

You can create a thread-local copy of any object:

```
 private static final ThreadLocal<MyObject> operator =
     new ThreadLocal<MyObject>() {
         @Override 
         protected MyObject initialValue() {
             // return thread-local copy of the "MyObject"
     }
 };
```

Later in your code, when a specific thread needs to get its own local copy, all it needs to do is: `operator.get()`. In reality, the implementation of `ThreadLocal` is similar to what you've described - a Map of `ThreadLocal` values for each Thread. Only the `Map` is not static, and is actually tied to the specific thread. This way, when a thread dies, it takes its `ThreadLocal` variables with it.

Comment: No you perfectly got my problem, I'll try this, thank you !!

Comment: This. Just one comment: since Java 8, it's easier to create it using a lambda, for example: `ThreadLocal<String> operator = ThreadLocal.withInitial( ()->"value");`